# height=100% do not work

Tags: html, css

the code below are all height=100%, it works fine in chrome but it displayes very strange in firefox and ie7!it is not exactly the 100% height.anyone knows? thanks a million.

```
<iframe src ="demoFramesetLeftFrame.jsp" name="treeframe" id="treeframe" 
        width=200px height=100% frameborder=0>
</iframe>
 <iframe src="middle.html" name="middle" id="middle"
        width=200px height=100% frameborder=0>
</iframe>
<iframe src="test.html" name="basefrm" id="basefrm"
        width=200px height=100% frameborder=0>
</iframe>
```

Comment: this might help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263968/iframe-not-expand-to-100-height

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need a container div, with a min-height property.  Writing 100% height in HTML for some reason is one of the hardest things to do.

Here are some tutorials on how 100% height can be achieved

http://www.dave-woods.co.uk/?p=144

http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum83/200.htm

Comment: hi tom,thanks for you replay!but i tried everything i could but it still not work.
1. i add a parent container its css code is below
#container {
 min-height: 100%;
 border:0;
 padding:0;
 margin:0; 
}
2. change the body height
html, body {
 height: 100%;
}
3. make all the frame position absoulte
#treeframe{
 position: absoulte;
 height: 100%;
 width:30%
}
#middle{
 position: absoulte;
 height: 100%;
 width:60%
}
#basefrm{
 position: absoulte;
 height: 100%;
 width:10%
}
but it still not work! i am very confused.